# Comprehensive css reset

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-reset

I have a javascript code that generates an html content on the user's page. The problem is that the styles used by the user affect my html code. I want to completely reset all css under my container class/id, how can i do that ?

For example the normal css reset styles don't reset table borders, background colors etc.

Comment: I don't get your question

Comment: ...you write CSS overrides for everything.

Comment: If your script requires a complete reset of styles, you're doing something wrong. Add the styles needed to your elements, don't reset the users styles.

Comment: Just make sure every element in your generated html code has a style defined by you. It will automatically override any style already defined on page (outside your code block).

Comment: I want to override / reset all css elements only under my html code (e.g. start with specific id).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe for your code to not be affected by css on the current user page .

```
<iframe src="YourURL" ></iframe>
```